# AngularJs local variable weird behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the code in the `controller`

```
cat1=[];

$.getJSON('categories/1/', function(data) {
    cat1 = data; //returns a JSON
});
//cat2..4 are some JSONs
$scope.pictures=[cat1,cat2,cat3,cat4,cat5];
```

The problem is that seems like `cat1=[]` and `cat1=data` are different variables, cause `pictures[cat1]` always returns `[]`

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `$.getJSON` is an async request and is still processing when you try and log. Also, don't use jQuery with Angular, use Angular's `$http` (this way a `$digest` cycle is triggered and everything stays in sync):

```
$http.get("categories/1/").success(function(data) {
    cat1 = data; //returns a JSON
    $scope.pictures=[cat1,cat2,cat3,cat4,cat5];
});
```

Dont forget to add `$http` as a dependency in your controller:

```
app.controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {

}]);
```

Comment: I have problems with `$http.get` in angularJS v1.3.3 it doesn't works and the whole angular codes goes down!

Comment: @AlexJolig -- Errors in the console?

Comment: I don't get any errors. Angular template tags just show up in html and I know its because angular hits some exceptions with $http.get

Comment: Ahh, did you include `$http` as a dependency in your controller?

Comment: Yes I did. `angular.module('imageListPagination').controller('sampleCtrl',['$scope', function($scope, $http){`

Comment: @AlexJolig -- No you didnt, see my example - you're missing the `$http` in your bracket string notation. And there's definitely an error in your console.